# Best way to prompt user for additional demographic info?

Tags: forms, methodology, surveys, profile

Trying to better profile our donors for marketing purposes. Short pop up survey? Append to registration? Email? But most people disregard such emails as spam, and adding an additional field to registration discourages people from completing registration. If you could screenshot examples of what various websites do that work or don't work, that would be EXTREMELY helpful.

Comment: You have answered your question. Demographic information is considered intrusive, and unlikely to be filled in truthfully unless the user is at the left end of the IQ distribution. Please also see this: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38154/are-age-verification-banners-effective To put it bluntly, my age is none of your business.

Answer (score 6):

You can **use gamification elements** to engage users into filling their profiles. One of the examples is engaging users to complete LinkedIn profile:

[image: Complete LinkedIn profile]

Some gamification tricks for user motivation are:

1. Make form filling meaningful for donors. You could explain why it is so important to fill the form.
2. Provide some kind of PBL (Points-Badges-Leaderboard) as visual feedback for those donors who completed the form.
3. Make question more [fun and game-like](http://www.research-live.com/features/more-than-a-game/4006083.article).

And [make good form](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11121/what-makes-a-good-form) for your task!

Another way to get more information from users is using they profiles from social networks.

Comment: +1 for "You could explain why it is so important to fill the form."  Presumably donors want to help your cause.  If you explain that the information will help you to better collect more donations, they will see it as a no-cost way to further support the cause, rather than an annoyance.

Comment: Stack exchange uses gamification by giving a bronze badge for filling out your user profile. Some of us will do anything for a shiny virtual bronze badge :)

Comment: I would point out the importance of giving 'small steps' to achieve the 100% mark. The tips you see in 'Profile Completion Tips'.

Comment: @rk, Small=easy executed, I agree with you!

Answer (score 2):

As you're considering this, also make sure that you clearly state that this will not be used or sold in any way and that you're only using this for informational purposes. A big part of asking for this information is that your users have to trust you. If you give any indication that you're going to break that trust, not only will that keep them from filling out this form, it could harm their overall perceptions of charity as well.

Answer (score 1):

**The way you ask is almost as important as how and when you ask.**

If you're dealing with donors, try to appeal to the same cause that brought them there to donate.  For example, if I'm collecting donations for the Humane Society, I would have a message similar to:

> **Help animals closer to home!**
>
> We are working to get your donated funds in to the communities that need it most, help us out by giving us a little bit of information about **your community!**
>
> Insert Survey link

**People want a good reason to spend their time on optional information**.